# precision specifiers as a preprocessor variable

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, printf

How can I determine a "precision specifiers" in a function like printf global as a  preprocessor variable? I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define tostring(x) #x
#define Prc  tostring(20)
```

and want in the printf as follows:

```
FILE *cout;
cout = fopen("c_out", "w"); 
 for(Sn=1;Sn<12;Sn++){
   for(In=1;In<519;In++){
     for(Epn=1;Epn<11;Epn++){
fprintf(cout, "%d %d %d %d %d:  %.Prce \n",Tn,Dn,Sn,In,Epn,   coeffTopDiaSpIntEp[Tn][Dn][Sn][In][Epn]); 
                            }
                        }
                     }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
"%d %d %d %d %d:  %." Prc "e \n"
```

Comment: unfortunately it dose not work because:                            _error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Prc’_

Comment: @maniA Why did you write `)`? replace `"%d %d %d %d %d:  %.Prce \n"` by `"%d %d %d %d %d:  %." Prc "e \n"`.

Comment: I wrote exactly: fprintf(cout, "%d %d %d %d %d: %." Prc "Qe  \n",Tn,Dn,Sn,In,Epn,   coeffTopDiaSpIntEp[Tn][Dn][Sn][In][Epn]);

Comment: @maniA `Q` is not a standard. and also It was added in the comments here.